# A problem from Probability Theory class: find the probability using geometry

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

In a combine in some cases the same worker serves two machines, which work independently of each other.  Numerous observations have been made and as a result they have shown that each machine for the set time T = 30 minutes requires the intervention of the worker with a length of time t = 5 minutes.  Calculate the probability that the length t that required the intervention of the worker one of the machines to require the intervention of the worker and the other machine when he is busy with the other.

My teacher solved by taking 0<=x<=30min and y the same interval and then she took the inequality |x-y|<=5 then we have two cases first line in coordinate system:x-y<=5 and Second line x-y>=5 and she draw them in coordinates system but I don’t understand this solution. Could someone explain this solution or another solution but it has to be solved with Geometric Probability.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  You'll get a better response if your questions are easy to read.

Comment: "Calculate the probability that the length $t$ that required the intervention of the worker one of the machines to require the intervention of the worker and the other machine when he is busy with the other,"  is incomprehensible.  Try to restate it, or if you can't, give an example of what you intend.